# Why property of the object is null after I set the value?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this type:

```
public partial class ReportTrafficDepartment
{
    public int _id;

    public System.Nullable<int> _siteNum;

    public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _dateReport;

    public string _siteName;

    public System.Nullable<int> _prog1;

    public System.Nullable<int> _progLayout1;

    public System.Nullable<int> _prog2;
}
```

And this function:

```
private void setDate(IEnumerable<ReportTrafficDepartment> report, int year, int month)
{
    report.Select(r => r.dateReport = new System.DateTime(year, month, 1));
}
```

As you can see I try to iterate through collection of the ReportTrafficDepartment objects and set dateReport property.

but after method is executed the property of all the ReportTrafficDepartment objets is null.

Any wht I do wrong?Why property of all the ReportTrafficDepartment objets is null?

Comment: You have a typo, `dateReport ` doesn't exists in `ReportTrafficDepartment`, `_dateReport ` does. Furthermore, what `select` does is to project the source data into a different one, so you're not affecting the source elements.

Comment: Don’t do this, using linq to achieve side effects is normally a very bad idea. Your problem is that linq *is lazy*, you are not iterating the projection so the assignment is never happening.

Comment: @InBetween should I use foreach?

Comment: @Michael In this case you can because you're modifying the elements not the iterable.

Comment: Yes, that would be much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don’t do this, using linq to achieve side effects is normally a very bad idea.

Your problem is that linq *is lazy*, you are not iterating the projection so the assignment is never happening. This is one of the reasons why side effects in linq queries can lead to very unexpected results.

If you are really bent on doing this, you have to make `SetDate` iterate the `Select` query eagerly calling `Count()`, `ToList()`, etc. But again, this is a bad idea, simply use a `foreach` block to do this.